# OPA mapi syntax error

Tags: opa

So I have a database record that contains a field with a list(string) I would like to convert this list of strings to some xhtml to display.

I've written the following function:

```
display_lp(path) = (
  do List.mapi(x, characterlp -> <div class="show_content" id=#show_content > {x} :    <textarea class="edit_content" id=#edit_content_lp cols="20" rows="1"> {characterlp} </textarea></div> ), /characters[path]/lifepaths -> y
  XMLConvert.of_list_using("","","",y)
)
```

however it doesn't compile. It gives me a syntax error:

> Syntax error at line 270, column 188
>   The error may be in the following citation, usually in the red part (starting at ⚐) or just before:
>   <<)
>       void
>   )
>
> display_lp(path) = (
>    do List.mapi(x, characterlp ->  {x} :  {characterlp}  )⚐, /characters[path]/lifepaths -> y
>    XMLConvert.of_list_using("","","",y)
>   )
>
> display(path) = (
>
> > >
> >     Hint: expected  
> >     (while parsing  starting at line 270, column 188)
> >     Error
> >     Syntax error

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i guess what you wanted to do :

```
display_lp(path) =
  y = List.mapi(
    x, characterlp ->
      <div class="show_content" id=#show_content>
      {x}:
      <textarea class="edit_content" id=#edit_content_lp cols="20" rows="1">
      {characterlp}
      </textarea>
      </div>
  , /characters[path]/lifepaths)
  XmlConvert.of_list_using(<></>,<></>,<></>,y)
```

1. First, your List.mapi is mis-parenthesed
2. Secondly, I don't understand your `-> y` after
   `/characters[path]/lifepaths`, i guess you wanted to put the result
   of List.mapi in the `y` variable.
3. Third, there is a typo : this is `XmlConvert` and NOT `XMLConvert`
   (uppercase)
4. Finally, XmlConvert has for signature :  `xhtml, xhtml, xhtml,
   list(xhtml)`

   That means you must provide type xhtml for the first 3 arguments,
   which is not compatible with the type string "" :)

   The equivalent of "" in xhtml is <>

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much and yes I should have explained it better but you figured out what I wanted.

Comment: N.B : if you don't need to put separators before, beetween and at the end of your xhtml list, you can directly use the xhtml list in `y` : just return `<>{y}</>` and it will work ;)